# C++ ostreams implemented over C fprintf()

Tags: open-source, library, software-development, c++, formatter

I'm looking for a library offering an `std::ostream` implemented on top of something other than the operating system's calls. It should be implemented either using C-style `printf()` commands, or alternatively, over some generic underlying primitives which I could replace.

Required features:

- Gratis.
- Libre.

Desired features:

- Actively maintained.
- Available under the Apache Public License v2.
- Available under 3-BSD or 2-BSD.
- Tested on both Linux and Windows.
- Some constexpr functionality (yes, I know that' not quite like C++ ostreams)
- Header-only would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think [uSTL](https://msharov.github.io/ustl/) might fit the bill.

Its ostream implementation appears to be based on c style primitives.

Source:

See both [here](https://msharov.github.io/ustl/#Streams) (quote: "Most calls use snprintf for output and thus use whatever locale libc uses") and the source itself, e.g. [here](https://github.com/msharov/ustl/blob/master/sostream.cc) , which uses only vsnprintf as far as I can see.

License:  It's [MIT licensed](https://github.com/msharov/ustl/blob/master/LICENSE).

Is it maintained?

Well, the main page says it's obsolete since C++11, but the git repo appears to be alive and well (last commit made a few months ago).

It says it isn't supported on Windows, only on Linux, but there's [this repo](https://github.com/gerozinkdev/ustl-windows) (uSTL-Windows). It looks abandoned, but it's a start.

It even uses some constexpr functionality, as per your request. 
Source: [this github search](https://github.com/msharov/ustl/search?q=constexpr&unscoped_q=constexpr).